# How do you prevent IP address leakage on a Mac while using VPN?

Tags: vpn, ip

I would like to prevent my real IP address from leaking to websites that I visit using Safari on OS X.

Do i need to configure my firewall? How ? What if my VPN connection accidentally drops? Is there anything else to worry about that could leak my real IP?

Comment: The VPN should modify your routing table, so that all outgoing  traffic to `0.0.0.0` (default route) goes via VPN, and to your VPN it goes via your standard router IP e.g. `192.168.1.1`. It may depend on what VPN software you are using. If it's not happening, you can run post-VPN script to enable it. See `netstat -nr` to view your routing table. If you would configure such routing table permanently, you'd be normally able to connect to VPN only and reach the reast of the internet via VPN only.

Comment: So instead of using DHCP, you can configure static IP address with static route only to your VPN and no default `0.0.0.0` route at all. So after booting your system and establishing your LAN connection, you can reach only VPN. That's just the basic option without firewall. In more complex situations like public WIFI you might setup firewall.

Comment: Please do not post the same question on multiple StackExchange sites http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/247861/145449

Answer (score 1):

Your IP can leak in a number of ways, but commonly through DNS or WebRTC. The first step would be to identify a leak using websites like [DoILeak](https://www.doileak.com/) or [DNS leak test](https://dnsleaktest.com/). Then take it from there - make sure you're using the correct DNS servers, disable WebRTC (though AFAIK Safari isn't vulnerable), and so on.

A very quick Google search came up with some good results, for example [this guide to IP leaks](https://www.bestvpn.com/blog/31750/a-complete-guide-to-ip-leaks/).